# cannot scan QR code for login whatsapp web version

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

using 3 inch display phone, cannot scan QR code for login. any idea to solve this?

Comment: Well, you don't need to install some third party QR scanner rather than the QR scanner can be found by opening whatsapp> Menu>Whats app Web. Use that QR scanner to scan the QR code !

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you can't do it with a display that is smaller than 4 inches... Normally, the built-in scanner in Whatsapp has an "OK, got it" button at the bottom of the instruction screen that blocks the camera. On my 3,5 inch model, this button is cut off, so I can't remove the message.

No Chance.